# No JRE 1.8 virtual machine on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: java, macos

I have install JRE 1.8 from Oracle site. But there is no jre dir for it.
java -version still returns:
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)

When I open config app for it it shows this [image: JRE settings]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is how to set 1.8 version to use by default

Comment: You have to install the JRE 1.8 and JDK 1.8. I just did this for Mac OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Add such shell to your $HOME/.bash_profile

```
 alias setJdk6='export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)'
 alias setJdk7='export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)'
 alias setJdk8='export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)'
 export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

2 . Run command  `source ~/.bash_profile`

3 . Then type "setJdk7" to use JDK7, "setJDK8" to use JDK8

Comment: But command /usr/libexec/java_home -V returns:
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Notice that -v is lowercase, not uppercase! the correct command is: /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is not enough to install JRE on Mac OS to have it registered and listed by /usr/libexec/java_home -V command. You have to install full JDK for it.